# print the successfull downloads using DownloadManager and DownloadManager.Query

Tags: android

I want to print the list of successfully download files which are listed by the **Download** program. The **Downloads** program lists 3 files which are downloaded sucessfully. The code below does not work. The code has been run in the emulator.

```
package com.talespinkit.downloadinfodeleter;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private DownloadManager downloadManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
     }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Query q = new Query();
        q.setFilterByStatus(DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL);
        Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(q);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(cursor.getCount())); // prints 0
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) { // Does not enters this loop
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnCount()));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Get your downloaded file name from sd Card using following:

File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

String sdCardPath = sdCard.getAbsolutePath();

File fileDir= new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "your file name");